# Middleware redirecting loop error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am trying to redirect users based on which role they enter in the registration page, however I keep getting the 'redirect too many times' error. I think its because I am using both the auth and guest mddlewares on the home page however I can not seem to fix it

Web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();

// Using middleware guest (Redirect If Authenticated) to check role and redirect to right route.
Route::middleware(['guest'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});


Route::prefix('referrer')->group(function(){

    /* need a more advanced middleware to give a notification when a brand user hits the
    *  referrer register/login page.
    *  e.g. logout and switch account, or simply make the referrer auth pages not accessible.
    */

    Route::get('/login/{program_id?}', 'ReferrerController@showLoginForm')->name('referrer.login')->middleware('guest');
    Route::post('/login/{program_id?}', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('referrer.login.user');
    Route::get('/', 'ReferrerController@getHome')->name('referrer.home')->middleware('auth');
    
//program middieware
    Route::middleware(['program.exist'])->group(function(){
        Route::get('/register/{program_id?}', 'ReferrerController@showRegistrationForm')->name('referrer.register');
        Route::post('/register/{program_id?}', 'ReferrerController@register')->name('referrer.register.user');
    });
});
```

Register Controller:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'role' => ['required', 'integer', 'between:1,3'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'role_id' => $data['role'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        return $user;
    }

    protected function redirectTo() {
        $role = auth()->user()->role_id;

        switch ($role) {
            case '3':
                return RouteServiceProvider::REF_HOME;
                break;
            case '1':
            //temp set as brand home
                return RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN_HOME;
                break; 
            default:
                return RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Home Controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
       
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
             // User role
             $role = Auth::user()->role->name;

             switch ($role) {
                 //role_id = 3
                 case 'referrer':
                     return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::REF_HOME);
                     break;
                //role_id = 1
                 case 'admin':
                 //temp set as brand home
                     return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN_HOME);
                     break; 
                 default:
                     return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
                     break;
             }

        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can't use the `auth` and `guest` middleware on the same route ... there is no way for someone to pass through both of those middleware as they are either authenticated or not, so one will always redirect them away ... having said that there should never be a time you would think you need both as its not possible

Comment: @lagbox How do I fix this, I have tried removing some code and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

your index function in the HomeController has auth and guest middlewares, just use one of them only.